# Polynomial regression sorting x

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

After running k-means on my data and dividing my observations into different clusters i've been trying to now plot my polynomial regression. However it's quite messy and not how i expected a polynomial line to look like. I understand that sorting x would propably help me fix that problem. But how do i sort x axis? I've searched for an answer but i haven't found anything that could help me.I'm new to python and i have been trying to get a good plot for several weeks now and it has been driving me crazy.

plot:
[image]

code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('D:\Mall_Customers.csv', usecols = ['Age', 'Annual Income (k$)','Spending Score (1-100)'])


x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, max_iter=100, random_state=0)
y_kmeans= kmeans.fit_predict(x)

mydict = {i: np.where(kmeans.labels_ == i)[0] for i in range(kmeans.n_clusters)}

dictlist = []
for key, value in mydict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)

df0 = df[df.index.isin(mydict[2].tolist())]
X = df0[['Age', 'Annual Income (k$)',]]
Y = df0['Spending Score (1-100)']



from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=0)

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures()
X_polynom = poly_reg.fit_transform(x_train)

PolyReg = LinearRegression()
PolyReg.fit(X_polynom, y_train)


plt.scatter(x_train.iloc[:, 1], y_train, color='red')

plt.plot(x_train, PolyReg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(x_train)),   color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Age. Annual income')
plt.ylabel('Spending Score')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to plot `x_train` against `PolyReg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(x_train))`. Rather try plot something like `np.arange(40,80)` against `PolyReg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(np.arange(40,80))`. This makes much more sense that regressing on arbitrary unsorted points, and then sorting later. Just regress on nice sorted points covering your domain.

Comment: But saying that, take a look at your data (the red dots), do they really look like something polynomial regression is going to help you with? What exactly do you plan to do with the outcome?

Comment: It's for a project, one of the requirements is to show different types of regression and show which one is best. Tried linear at first and obviously my data isn't linear at all. And now trying polynomial but i see that it won't be much help. So you're saying to sort my points before i plot them? How would i go by doing that?

Comment: No, to very clear you absolutely should not sort your points before you plot them!

Comment: I'm saying when you are doing your predictions, just predict on a nice even range of points as given by `np.arange`. Don't predict on `x_train` if you want a line plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would think polynomial regression has any business being done on that data, but if you want to plot its outcome it makes much more sense to predict against a nice, evenly spaced set of points instead of `x_train`. Try this instead of your line that plots the blue line:

```py
x_reg_line = np.arange(40, 80)[:, None]
y_reg_line = PolyReg.predict(x_reg_line) # Don't fit again here! You have already fit your model earlier!
plt.plot(x_reg_line, y_reg_line, color="blue")
```

Comment: First of all thanks for making the effort in helping me! Now when i try this i get the error
```Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1)``` 
Also which regression type would be best on this data?

Comment: None - there is cleary no relationship in your data. That error message literally tells you the fix... see my edit